# What file and cron file run when content scheduling content goes live?

Tags: magento2, schedule

I am understand the schedule update files work on save and delete, but i am not understand when schedule product goes live which file or event triggered for the showing schedule content on frontend.
I am trying to create the functionality the product goes live then content notification email receive